# Concatenate string on repeater with Angular Translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I want to concatenate a string on a repeater using Angular Translate inside "small" tag to put a description. What i must do?

```
<li ng-repeat="subtype in type">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioType" ng-value="subtype" ng-model="dialogModel.type"> 
        {{ subtype.name }} <small>{{ 'subtype.name + "_DESCRIPTION"' | translate }}</small>
    </label>
</li>
```

Now it shows me a literal string, I don't know how concatenate an Angular Translate string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `subtype.name + "_DESCRIPTION` is the string you want to translate on, the outter `'` is not needed.

```
{{ subtype.name }} <small>{{ (subtype.name + "_DESCRIPTION") | translate }}</small>
```

btw, if you have many many `subtype` to repeat, the `translate` may cause a performance problem , so try to use `$filter('translate') in ctrl` or simply use  `one-time binding` with "::", it seems that you need not to update the `_DESCRIPTION` again after it rendered in your case.

```
{{ subtype.name }} <small>{{ ::(subtype.name + "_DESCRIPTION") | translate }}</small>
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to append the string `"_DESCRIPTION"` to the result of the 'translation' then simply place the static text *after* the Angular expression:

```
<small>{{ subtype.name | translate }}_DESCRIPTION</small>
```